Error -31 calling FCGX_Accept_r CoastRD libfcgi2.dll
I am trying to create a FCGI application using coastrd libfcgi2.dll.
Does anyone know what is a Error -31 executing an FCGX_Accept_r?
\-------- DEBUG BEGIN ---------
Version= 0

10-24-2024 13:44:35 \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~ Init
COMPUTERNAME = FRANCESCOE-V
_FCGI_SHUTDOWN_EVENT_ = 0
_FCGI_X_PIPE_ = \\.\\pipe\\IISFCGI-9413b0bc-7991-4604-ba68-bb9befb4e526

ResetEvent()=0, Termination Event handle is Invalid
GetLastError=0 - The operation completed successfully.
ConnMode = FD_PIPE_IIS
GetNamedPipeInfo: OutputBuffSz= 4096, InputBuffSz= 4096
10-24-2024 13:44:35 \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~ Request Complete

Error: -31 in FCGX_Accept_r(), DisconnectNamedPipe Error=  0 - The operation completed successfully.
DLL_PROCESS_DETACH
\------- DEBUG END --------

Thanks.
I am able to execute a positive FCGX_InitRequest, initializing my structure that are built in this way:
    public struct FCGX_Stream
    {
        public IntPtr pData;
        public uint LenStored;
        public uint Capacity;
        public uint CurPos;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 12)]
        public string Reserved;
    }

    public struct FCGX_Request
    {
        public int Version;
        public int ReqCount;
        public int Role;
        public int ConnFlags;
        public int ReqMethod;
        public int ContLen;
        public IntPtr pzQuery;
        public int nParam; 
        public IntPtr envp; 
        public IntPtr pIn;
        public IntPtr pOut;
        public IntPtr pErr;
        public IntPtr pzLastErr;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 108)]
        public string Reserved;
    }

But I have a -31 error when the Accept_r receive a posted request.
